# Converting to base 10 in java?

Tags: java, recursion

I have a homework assignment where I have to covert any base to base 10. I have some given numbers, which are the "basen". I have to convert those bases to base 10. The only part that I am stuck in is this part of the code:

```
answer = ; // Not sure what I have to put in here
```

I have seen some other posts about converting to base ten, but I am just not sure how to how to incorporate them into my code.

```
public class BaseN {

public static final int BASEN_ERRNO = -1;
public static int digit  = 0;

public static void main(String[] argv) {
  basen(512, 6);
  basen(314, 8);
  basen(49, 5);
  basen(10101, 2);
}

public static void basen(int n, int b) {
  int ans = basen(n, b, 1, 0);
  if (ans == BASEN_ERRNO)
     System.out.println(n + " is not a valid base-" + b + " number");
  else
     System.out.println(n + " base-" + b + " = " + ans + " base-10");
}

public static int basen(int number, int base, int placevalue, int answer) {
  if (number == 0) return answer;
  digit = number % 10;
  if (digit >= base) return BASEN_ERRNO;
  answer = 1;// not sure what to put here
  number = 0;
  placevalue = 0;
  return basen(number, base, placevalue, answer);
}
}
```

Comment: When dealing with base-n representations of a number, you're implicitly talking about a string of characters. Your code is entirely dealing with `int` values, which represent numbers in binary (base 2) and have no capacity for representing numbers in other bases. You're going to have to rethink the definition of your problem so the input is a string in one base and the output is a string in base 10.

Comment: Java has a useful routine for you: `Integer.parseInt(numberString, base)` will throw a `NumberFormatException` if the provided String does not represent a valid number for the given base. If that's not what your teacher would be fine with can you tell us what he/she wants you exactly to do?

Comment: @Ted Hopp gave you the big secret, that a number just is, and that bases are about strings. Are you familiar with number bases? For a base `b` it's sequence of coefficients `d, 0 <= d < b`.  Taking whole numbers, each position `p` of the string starting a 0 from the right represents a term `(b^p) * d`. (`^` here means exponentiation.) The "ones" place is `b^0 * d` = `d`. The next place left is `b * d`, then `b^2 * d`, `b^3 * d`, etc. So don't divide or mod by `10` to get, say, a base `5` string. The number is just the sum of those terms, the string is the sequence of numerals `d`.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the following algorithm. Lets say you are given `String number` which represents the number you want to convert to decimal form and `int base` which represents the base of given number. You can implement function  `int convertToNumber(char c);`  which accepts one character representing one digit from your number and will map characters to numbers like this:

0 -> 0,
1 -> 1,
... ,
A-> 10,
B -> 11,
... ,
F -> 15,
...

Then you just iterate through your given string and multiply this functions output with base to the power of iteration. For example, convert number A32(hexadecimal):
A32 = convertToNumber(A) * b ^ 2 + convertToNumber(3) * b ^ 1 + convertToNumber(2) * b ^ 0 = 10 * 16 ^ 2 + 3 * 16 ^ 1 + 2 * 16 ^ 0 = 10 * 16 * 16 + 3 * 16 + 2 = 2610 (decimal).

```
public class BaseConvert {

    public static int convertDigitToNumber(char c) throws Exception {
        if(c >= '0' && c <= '9') return c - '0';
        if(c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') return c - 55;
        if(c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') return c - 97;
        throw new Exception("Invalid digit!");
    }

    public static int convertToBase(String number, int base) throws Exception {
        int result = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++){
            result += convertDigitToNumber(number.charAt(i)) * (int)Math.pow(base, number.length() - i - 1);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try{
            System.out.println(convertToBase("732", 8));
            System.out.println(convertToBase("A32", 16));
            System.out.println(convertToBase("1010", 2));
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could look at a k length number of base n like this:
x(0)*n^(k-1) + x(1)*n^(k-2) + ... + x(k-1)*n^1 + x(k)*n^0
Where x(0), x(1), ..., x(k) is the digit at position k from the left.

So, if you are trying to convert, say, 101 base 2 to base 10 you would do the following :
1 * 2^2 + 0 * 2^1 + 1 * 2^0 = 4 + 0 + 1 = 5 base 10

say you want to convert the number 352 from base 6:
3 * 6^2 + 5 * 6^1 + 2 * 6^0 = 108 + 30 + 2 = 145 base 10

What you're looking for code wise is something like this :

```
int[] digits = {3, 5, 2};
int base = 6;
int answer = 0;
for(int i = digits.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    answer += digits[i] * Math.pow(base,digits.length-i-1); 
}
return answer;
```

which will return 145.

Hopefully even though my implementation is iterative you should be able to apply it to your recursive implementation as well.